# All.js suddenly produce error start from 21/9/2012, it work for two years

Tags: browser, facebook-javascript-sdk

Chrome works, IE not works, 
Safari and Firefox sometimes work after refresh. This error suppress all javascript on my site from working! my site is now paralayzed by facebook javascript sdk. It only started yesterday, it work fine in the past 2 years in a my high traffic production site.

in IE, Safari:
SCRIPT5022: Error all.js, line 43 Char 128

which is

__d("Assert",["AssertionError","sprintf"],function(a,b,c,d,e,f){var g=b('AssertionError'),h=b('sprintf');function i(p,q){if(!p)throw new g(q);return p;}function j(p,q,r){var s=Object.prototype.toString.call(q),t=/\s(\w*)/.exec(s)[1].toLowerCase();i(~ES5(p,'indexOf',true,t),r||h('Expression is of type %s, not %s',t,p));return q;}function k(p,q,r){i(q instanceof p,r||'Expression not instance of type');return q;}var l={isInstanceOf:k,isTrue:i,type:j,define:function(p,q){l.isString(p);l.isFunction(q);p=p.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+p.substring(1).toLowerCase();l['is'+p]=function(r,s){i(q(r),s);};}},m=['Array','Boolean','Date','Function','Null','Number','Object','Regexp','String','Undefined'],n=m.length;while(n--){var o=m[n];l['is'+o]=ES5(j,'bind',true,null,o.toLowerCase());}e.exports=l;});

using the debug function of IE, the error seems coming from : this code:

throw new g(q)

As facebook just make it a compacted and directly download from facebook. I have no way to debug it or change it. Please advise what info I can gather to let you know more.

Comment: What is the error? Basic debugging should provide you with an error message at the least.

Comment: The error message is just a word "Error", it seems facebook made its code to hide the error message, and it seems from the code: throw new g(q) is the source of error.

Comment: Read the error message. According to your last edit, the error is occurring at `throw new g(q)`. In the error message, it says `function i(p,q){if (!p) throw new g(q);return p;}`, and that's the only place `throw` is used in the message. So you need to see where `function i` is called, and look to see what is passed as `p`, and keep tracing back until you find out why `!p` happens.

Comment: There is a lot of function call i(), and when you trace back it is __d("Assert"....) (you cannot find any function naming __d) and I really don't know how to trace back from that point..I guess the situation is "if you get error call i()" and every where can call this function, making it impossible to trace...The worse part is this throw stop all javascript file from running, as my site rely heavily on ajax, facebook basically stopped my site from functioning....

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem on a Drupal site with Drupal for Facebook and my workaround was to put a `try{}catch(e){}` around `FB.XFBML.parse(elem);` at line 38 of fb.js. The problem seems to stem from `elem` not being of type HTMLDocument, but you can't check this, because IE9 does not have this type.

If you are not using Drupal, then look for the function call to FB.XFBML.parse.